# Need help connecting an Excel data sheet such that each line of the Excel sheet can be queried into a seperate Excel form

Tags: excel, forms, linq, excel-formula, extract

Need help connecting an Excel data sheet such that each line of the Excel sheet can be queried into a seperate Excel form.
Example
Data from Excel sheet
[My Excel Data with headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KLsz.png)

The above data needs to be queried into the form below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leA1s.png)

I have tried VLOOKUP and Data Connections.  Shucks, I don't know what I am doing.

Comment: `VLOOKUP` should work fine, as long as you have a unique ID for each row of the data. Do you?

Comment: I do not.  Can you provide an example based on my images

Comment: You need to reference something in your VLOOKUP, so that it returns the data from the correct row into your form. The issue you'll have if the reference you look up isn't unique, is that Excel will just return data for the first row found with that reference, i.e. Computer Literacy